# Angular 5 File Download using FileSaver Error

Tags: angular, filesaver.js

I'm trying to download a file using angular and rest service (java, spring-boot), but I am facing an issue with FileSaver in angular.

This is the code for angular side

```
    public searchAndDownload(searchRequest:any){
        const headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.append('Accept', 'text/csv');
        console.log('searching and downloading');
        return this.http.get('../download/', 
            {'observe':'response','params': searchRequest, 'headers': headers, 
         'responseType':'text'}).toPromise().then(res=>{
      this.saveToFileSystem(res);
    });
  }

  private saveToFileSystem(response) {
    console.log("file download response:", response);

    const contentDispositionHeader: string = response.headers.get('Content-Disposition');
    const parts: string[] = contentDispositionHeader.split(';');
    const filename = parts[1].split('=')[1];
    const blob = new Blob([response['body']], { type: 'text/csv' },);
    /*var url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(url);*/
    saveAs(blob,"search-csv.csv");
  }
```

I'm seeing the below error in saveAs function

```
    ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at DownloadService.webpackJsonp../src/app/download-service.service.ts.DownloadService.saveToFileSystem (download-service.service.ts:39)
    at download-service.service.ts:26
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4749)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:387)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:138)
    at zone.js:858
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4740)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at DownloadService.webpackJsonp../src/app/download-service.service.ts.DownloadService.saveToFileSystem (download-service.service.ts:39)
    at download-service.service.ts:26
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4749)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:387)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:138)
    at zone.js:858
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4740)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:809)
    at zone.js:861
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4740)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
    at ZoneTask.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:500)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1517)
    at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone.js:1543)
```

I can see response with headers properly. Infact, I can download the file, if I directly hit the url from the browser.

versions:
"@angular/core": "^5.2.0"
"file-saver": "^1.3.4"
"@types/file-saver": "^1.3.0",

I'm new to angular 5, am I missing something?

I followed [this](https://shekhargulati.com/2017/07/16/implementing-file-save-functionality-with-angular-4/) link to write the above code. Minor changes to http.get options were made to make it work in angular 5.

Comment: What's in line 26 of your `download-service.service.ts`?

Comment: It just calls the function 'saveToFileSystem' like 'this.saveToFileSystem(res);'

Comment: He probably meant line 39.

Comment: line 39 `saveAs(blob,"search-csv.csv");`